# How to set different width and height of view for different devices in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8

I'm having a problem with Xcode 8's new vary for traits. I have an `uiview` with 300x200 and `unbutton` with 50 top constraint to `uiview` in iPhone 7 screen size. What i want is that i want to change the `uiview` size to 350x250 for iPhone 7+, smaller width and height for iPhone SE screen size and also button's top constraint.

[image]

I tried to constraint using vary for traits but when i change the width of view in iPhone 7+, it also applied in iPhone 7 and also SE. How can i use this vary for traits.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you cannot.

Interface Builder only handles [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH19-SW4), and does not allow much more customisation.

You'll have to either:

- handle your changes and updating constraints programmatically *(in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for example)*
- or just having relative constraints *(for example: button width equal to superview with a multiplier of 0.9)*
- follow Apple principles and just creating one layout per size class and that's it